# jQuery datepicker - how to change the month using the API?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a jquery datepicker setup. I have customized this so that inside the datepicker div, I have created a custom menu with some months like so:

```
    <div class="custom_menu">
    <div class="month">January 2012</div>
    <div class="month">February 2012</div>
    <div class="month">March 2012</div>
    </div>
```

What I am looking to do is when the user clicks on a month I want the datepicker to update it's view with that month e.g. some psuedocode

```
$('.month').live('click', function(){

var newmonth = $(this).text(); //get the month in a suitable format

$('#current_datpicker').update('month', newmonth); //update the datepicker to show this month

});
```

Can I do something like this, looking at the API docmentation does not show anything...

**EDIT**

The problem I am facing is how to get the #current_datepicker (i.e. the correct datepicker id) when I have more than 1 instance of a datepicker on the page? Is the current datepicker trigger input id stored somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#current_datpicker').datepicker("setDate", newmonth + 'm');
```

[**source**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-setDate)

Though `$(this).text()` won't give you only the month, you need to remove the year:

```
var newmonth = $(this).text().split(" ")[0];
```

Comment: How do I get the correct datepicker ID if I am using more than 1 datepicker instance on my page?

Comment: I mean through the API - as the `$(.month).live('click', function...)` function will not be able to tell where to send the update to

Comment: @Ash. You can give the datepicker an id "matching" the div id. `<div id="firstDiv>` `<input id="firstDatepicker">`

Comment: @Ash. You do know datepicker is just an input, right? anyway you can open the datepicker with code. like this: `$('#current_datpicker').datepicker( "show" )`

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to use the `.datepicker( "setDate" , date )` method. I would suggest that when the user clicks a month, you set the date to the first day of that month.

You could use the `$.data()` jQuery mechanism to store the date information on each `div.` For example you could do `$('#').data('data', new Date('1/1/2012')`something along those lines.

Check out the [API](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-setDate).